# how to concat & substring a column value in cassandra

Tags: string, cassandra

I have one column mobilenumber in my table of Cassandra, i want to mask that mobile number like start 4 digit will be changed to 1111, for exp - i have a mobilenumber 9876543210 will be masked to 1111543210 (start 4 digits are changed to 1111)

I am not getting any sub string or con cat function in Cassandra, can somebody help me in resolving my problem

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

You can't do this at the moment on the server side. You would have to do this in your client code.

I say, at the moment, because Cassandra 3.0 will introduce User Defined Functions with https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-7395 (and others). So if you are willing to wait for the 3.0 release you would be able to do this by defining a UDF for the purpose.

Comment: This will be a really cool feature when it comes out.  But I wonder how well they'll perform?  I suppose it'll depend largely on the function code, but I can't imagine a string operation being very performant...especially on something like 10 million rows.